# using QString as argmuent in SLOT macro

Tags: qt, qt4.8

Is it possible to be used as an argument QString in SLOT macro?
PS. I mean a simple solution .. Not as in QMetaObject::connectSlotsByName().

Comment: I don't think so; the SLOT macro defines its contents at compile time. Can you do something like `QString slotName = SLOT(method());`, then pass that string into `connect`?

Comment: Unfortunately, no. I am writing to autoconnect method to my class with consist a lot of functions that differ in name prefix

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No you cannot pass `QString` to `SLOT` macro. But you can use `QString` for `connect`. Also `connect` cannot take `QString`, so you have to convert it to `const char *`. Simple example is:

```
QString slotName = SLOT(clicked());
connect(ui->pushButton, SIGNAL(clicked()), qPrintable(slotName));
```

`SLOT` just stringifies passed parameter and concatenate it with `1`:

```
# define SLOT(a)     qFlagLocation("1"#a QLOCATION)
```

If you don't want to use `SLOT` it's possible to write code like this:

```
QString slotName = QString::number(QSLOT_CODE) + "clicked()";
```

Comment: code:
connect(pAct,SIGNAL(triggered()),this,SLOT( qPrintable(SlotActionPrefix+pAct->objectName()) ));  

log:
Object::connect: No such slot MainWindow::qPrintable(pAct->objectName()) in .\mainwindow.cpp:91
Object::connect:  (sender name:   'actionIPBlur')
Object::connect:  (receiver name: 'MainWindowClass')
  
Does not work (
PS. QAction * pAct; const char* SlotActionPrefix = "act_";

Comment: You don't need to pass `qPrintable` to `SLOT` macro. Read the answer more attentively, please.

Answer (score 0):

This is raw code from my current project. It parses chat commands like /me customtext and calls cmd_me( const QString& params ); slot.
To introduce new command it's enough to create private slot with void cmd_*( const QString& ); signature.

Here is code:

```
void ConsoleController::onCommand( const QString& cmd )
    {
        if ( cmd.length() < 1 )
            return ;
        if ( cmd[0] != '/' )
            return ;

        const QMetaObject *meta = metaObject();

        int posParam = cmd.indexOf( ' ' );
        if ( posParam == -1 )
            posParam = cmd.length();
        const QString command = cmd.mid( 1, posParam - 1 ).toLower();
        const QString params = cmd.mid( posParam + 1 );
        const QString slotName = QString( "cmd_%1( const QString& )" ).arg( command );
        const QString normalizedSlotName = QMetaObject::normalizedSignature( slotName.toStdString().c_str() );

        for ( int i = 0; i < meta->methodCount(); i++ )
        {
            QMetaMethod method = meta->method( i );
            if ( method.methodType() != QMetaMethod::Slot )
                continue;

            const QString signature = method.signature();
            if ( normalizedSlotName == signature )
            {
                method.invoke( this, Q_ARG( QString, params ) );
                return ;
            }
        }

        log( QString( "Command \"%1\" not recognized, type /help to list all available commands" ).arg( command ) );
    }
```

You can take an idea and adapt it for your needs.

Comment: Thank you. Sori but I can not raised your karma